# In C#, how do I store large prime number?

Tags: c#, cryptography, key, diffie-hellman

Good day everyone,

I am attempting to implement the Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol in C#.
Before anything, this is **a test project**. I am aware that I should **NOT** use it for any real application. I am just doing this to learn a bit more about it.

Now, according to this RFC (3526), I need to use the prime number P=`2^6144 - 2^6080 - 1 + 2^64 * { [2^6014 pi] + 929484 }` and the generator G=`2`.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3526#page-6

But the prime number is a way too big ! Even for BigInteger !

How do I proceed now ?

EDIT:

I assume it's too large because this piece of code return a negative value :

```
string hexString = "...";
BigInteger number = BigInteger.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
Console.WriteLine("Converted 0x{0}\nto\n{1}.", hexString, number);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ffr7Ip

Comment: "*The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds*" -- are you *sure* it's too large for a BigInteger?

Comment: Well, this piece of code says so :
`string hexString = "...";
BigInteger number = BigInteger.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
Console.WriteLine("Converted 0x{0}\nto\n{1}.", hexString, number);`

hexString is the exadecimal number that can be found on the link in the main post.

Comment: Can you put a working repro into https://dotnetfiddle.net?

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ffr7Ip

Comment: Looks fine? It's interpreting it as a signed number, but stick a leading `0` on and it gets interpreted as an unsigned number: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cme8lI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigInteger.Parse` converts the hex string to binary. If the binary number start with a `1`, that will mean the number is signed. That is why it gives you a negative number. As @canton7 said, just prepend a `0` and you will be good to go.

Comment: Alternatively (and probably preferably), check whether it's negative, and negate it if so

Comment: I don't think that would work as signed numbers use two's compliment.